# interesting inequality for logarithms (comparison with the n-root function)

Tags: calculus

Let $n \in N$.

> Does there exist a constant $C(n) > 0$ and a  $\delta > 0$ such that,$ \left\lvert x\ln(x) - x - (y\ln(y) - y)\right\rvert \leq C(n)\left\lvert x^{1/n} - y^{1/n}\right\rvert,\ \ \forall x,y: (0<x<\delta) \land (0<y<\delta)$?

According to the wolfram, it appears that the inequality is true. But I don't have idea to how to prove. Could someone help me with a proof?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> let
>   $$x^{\frac{1}{n}}=a\in (0,\delta^{1/n}),y^{\frac{1}{n}}=b\in (0,\delta^{1/n})$$
>   then we have find $C(n)$ such
>   $$\left|na^n\ln{a}-a^n-nb^n\ln{b}+b^n\right|\le C(n)\left|a-b\right|$$

then we consider
$$f(x)= nx^n\ln{x}-x^n\Longrightarrow f'(x)=n\left[nx^{n-1}\ln{x}+x^{n-1}\right]-nx^{n-1}$$
so
$$f'(x)=n^2x^{n-1}\ln{x},x\in (0,\delta^{1/n})$$
since
$$\lim_{x\to 0}n^2x^{n-1}\ln{x}=n^2\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\ln{x}}{\frac{1}{x^{n-1}}}=0,n>1$$
so
$$f'(x)=n^2x^{n-1}\ln{x}\in (0,n^2\delta^{\frac{n-1}{n}}\ln{\delta^{1/n}})$$
so you can use [Mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) have
$$|na^n\ln{a}-a^n-nb^n\ln{b}+b^n|=|f(a)-f(b)|=|f'(\xi)||a-b|<n^2\delta^{\frac{n-1}{n}}\ln{\delta^{1/n}}|a-b|$$
let
$$C(n)=n^2\delta^{\frac{n-1}{n}}\ln{\delta^{1/n}}$$

Otherwise: Assmue $n=1$, I think we can't find it, because $$\ln{x}\to-\infty,x\to 0$$
so following I consider $n>1$